# Calling method with dot operator on list of objects

Tags: c#, list

I am relatively new to C# and in my assignment I am asked to create a list of object:

```
var A = new List<ObjectName>;
```

And do operation on this list by doing such function calls

```
int sum = A.Add(B); //B is also a List<ObjectName>
```

How do I implement such method in "ObjectName" class, I know you can do following with primitive datatypes:

```
   public int Add(ObjectName B){
        return this.Value + B.Value
}
```

How do I do the same when dealing with the lists? (In case I dont sound clear, I want to get the whole list which is calling the function Add() as well as whole list B which is passed as argument)

EDIT: Add() was just an example (as it was easy to demonstrate for primitive datatypes). I am not adding anything, I just want to access both caller list as well as passed list in same function, which is called by dot operator.

Comment: search for operator overload : `+` in your case

Comment: If you want to append `B` to `A`, you can use the built in `AddRange` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_AddRange_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__

Comment: Your first code line is invalid BTW.

Comment: @Ivan I do not want to append, with Add() function I want to perform action on all members of lists A and B, so I am trying to somehow get both lists in same function. (I know I can pass B to a function, but how do I access the caller, A)

Comment: @Ach113 `List<T>`'s `Add()` method is not an addition(+) method, it's just adding items to your `List`.

Comment: He doesn't mean List<T>.Add() as in, adding an item to the list. He just used Add as a general example of an operation, not knowing that Add() is actually a member of List<T>.

Comment: Ok, What you ask is unclear. So I will try to clarify with good old metaphor. You have 2 shoes box A and B. In them you have some money `A = new []{1, 5, 10}` and `B= new[]{2, 20, 50}`. By  `A.Add(B);`, You want sum to be a box containing the money from the other box, right ? Because the fact that the variable `sum` is an int mean it should be 88 in my exemple. the total of both box when you sum them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I implement such method in "ObjectName" class

**You cannot.** The method works on a `List<>` and nothing you do in your class will change that. **I strongly suggest you ask your teacher to clarify this.**

You can make your syntax compile by adding an extension method:

```
public static class ListOfObjectNameExtension
{
    public static int Add(this List<ObjectName> a, List<ObjectName> b)
    {
        // no idea what the result should actually be...
        return 42;
    }
}
```

The following:

```
int sum = A.Add(B);
```

will now compile, because we extended the `List<ObjectName>` to have an `.Add` method.

But again, I'm sure this is not what your teacher wanted, please go ask them to clarify the task.

Comment: I see, so lists cannot have methods called by dot operator at all right? The assignment prompt suggested that it did so that part confused me.

Comment: Honestly, I think it's a very good chance that extension methods might be the focus of the exercise.  I can't see a way to do this without them.

Comment: Lists can have *their own* methods called by the dot operator, that goes for all objects, that's not special to lists. If you want to call a method *as if it were a class method* you need extension methods. Or have access to the class' source code to modify it.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here.  The comment `How do I implement such method in "ObjectName" class` doesn't fit any of the code the OP posted.  To me, it just looks like `A.AddRange(B)`

Comment: @Archer `A.AddRange(B)` does not return an `int`.

Comment: I know that.  That doesn't change the fact that I believe the OP is asking how to concatenate 2 lists.  What they want `sum` to contain is another question.  For all we know it could be the length of the list after concatenation.  It's just unclear.

Answer (score 0):

To make a sum of object values use System.Linq namespace.
Put 'System.Linq' in using block. (Top of your program).
This is a quite useful library. Here info link [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

'Union' makes one general collection removing duplications and Sum - summarize your values of objects.
'Concat' makes one simple general collection including all your elements.

```
    public int MakeSumWithoutDuplications(List<ObjectName> a, List<ObjectName> b)
    {
        return a.Union(b).Sum(x => x.Value);
    }

    public int MakeGeneralSum(List<ObjectName> a, List<ObjectName> b)
    {
        return a.Concat(b).Sum(x => x.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Why you remove duplicates? Also, if `ObjectName` doesn't override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` it doesn't remove them.  Theres are too many assumptions here which i dont see in the question

Comment: You mean Concat(), not Union().

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's another question. Suppose he uses unique values :)

Comment: @IuriiMaksimov: well, then there is no need for the overhead anyway, use `Concat`

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but I'm -guessing- you want to add the sum of the values of .Value in every item in list A to the sum of the .Value properties in list B.

To do this, you can write an extension method for List:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static int SomeAddOperation(this List<ObjectName> listA, List<ObjectName> listB)
    {
        int sumA = 0;
        foreach(var someObject in listA)
        {
            sumA += someObject.Value;
        }

        int sumB = 0;
        foreach(var someObject in listB)
        {
            sumB += someObject.Value;
        }        

        return sumA + sumB;
    }
}
```

Then, you call it like this:

int sum = A.SomeAddOperation(B);